# Ограничение поля ввода в виджете Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, валидация, entry

Как в поле ввода (`Entry`) ограничить количество вводимых знаков до **`12`**?

Пытался так, но не получается:

```
...

def cht():
    s = self.F.get().strip()
    s = s[0] if s in range(0,12) else ''
    self.F.delete ('12', END)
    self.F.insert(INSERT, s)

    self.F = ttk.Entry(Form3)
    self.F.place(x=180, y=30)        
    self.F.bind('<KeyRelease>', cht)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Как использовать `validatecommand` для проверки вводимых пользователем данных в `Entry`**](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-validation/).

```
import tkinter as tk


def onValidate(d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
    print(f'\nOnValidate: ') 
    print(f'd={d}') # "d='%s'" % d
    print(f'i={i}') # "i='%s'" % i
    print(f'P={P}') # "P='%s'" % P
    print(f's={s}') # "s='%s'" % s
    print(f'S={S}') # "S='%s'" % S
    print(f'v={v}') # "v='%s'" % v
    print(f'V={V}') # "V='%s'" % V
    print(f'W={W}') # "W='%s'" % W
    # разрешать только в том случае, если длина строки <= 12  
    return (len(P) <= 12)

root = tk.Tk()

vcmd = (root.register(onValidate), 
        '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
        
entry = tk.Entry(root, 
    validate="key", 
    validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Блин как просто, все Супер ! Спасибо !!!

Comment: @АндрейК пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour